# CSS Transform one side of element, different on top and on bottom

Tags: css

I would like to transform one side of an element but on top different from bottom like in the image here:

[image]

I tried with:

```
transform-origin: left bottom;
transform: skewY(-3deg);
```

But it moves left side completelly (top and bottom).

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your best bet would be using an SVG path